# How to authorize by qr as in whatsapp?

Tags: python, django, flutter, dart, qr-code

*(I'm a beginner)* I would like to make an application on flutter, which will need to be registered and there will be certain data (taken and given books). Make a qr scanner in the same place.

there is a shelf with books, which can be accessed only if you scan qr on a computer (qr will not be permanent and will be updated every 1 minute for the sake of safety) and indicate which books you took and which ones you left. The data will be displayed on the client's phone (that is, the application on the client's phone has no functionality other than viewing data about books)
(I want to write the server part in python)

**question: how to log in via qr? or rather, how to send data when scanning qr?**

i know qr stores small data. how much should I make a qr generator that will store the access key (unfortunately, I also do not understand how to implement the access key to the accounts, and whether it will be safe to make the access key from which you can access all accounts) key (1234) when the scanned application should send example.com/qr/1234, but **how to access the correct account?**.

**Are there better ways to do this, and what resources would you recommend to explore?**

**I USED GOOGLE TRANSLATOR**

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_barcode_scanner this package is a good start to working with QR. Take your time and post specific problems you face along the way.

Comment: Check out [ask] to improve this question. Specifically [help/on-topic]